# Is it possible to adjust the size of squares (cells) in Seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Suppose I have a heatmap plot like this:

[image]

Using this data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


arr = np.array([[ 2,  2,  2,  8,  7,  7,  6,  5,  2,  7,  7,  8,  7,  5,  6,  6,  6],
       [ 8,  7,  5,  4,  4,  3,  9,  6,  7,  4,  3,  2,  8,  9,  3,  3,  3],
       [ 1,  3,  2,  2,  2,  3,  5,  3,  3,  2,  3,  3,  4,  1, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 3,  2,  4,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  1,  9,  9,  9],
       [ 7,  6,  7,  6,  6,  6,  2,  2,  5,  6,  5,  4,  7,  9,  9,  9,  9],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  4,  3,  4,  4,  8,  7,  3,  4,  5,  6,  3,  4,  4,  4],
       [ 3,  1,  1,  9,  9,  9,  3,  1,  8,  9,  9,  9,  1,  6,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  5,  5,  5,  5,  1,  2,  5,  6,  5, 10,  8,  8,  8,  8],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  2,  3,  2,  7,  3,  1,  3,  2,  2, 10,  8,  7,  7,  7],
       [ 5,  5,  2,  2,  2,  1,  1,  3,  3,  2,  1,  1,  5,  2,  7,  7,  7],
       [ 7,  9, 10,  3,  4,  4,  8,  9,  9,  3,  4,  6,  2,  3,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  3,  3,  3,  3,  1,  4,  4,  3,  4,  9, 10,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 4,  4,  3,  4,  4,  4,  3,  4,  3,  4,  4,  3,  2,  7, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 2,  1,  1,  8,  8,  8,  1,  4,  2,  8,  8,  8,  4,  1,  5,  5,  5],
       [ 9,  9,  8,  8,  8,  8,  5,  6,  8,  8,  8,  5,  1,  5,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  4,  2,  1,  5,  5,  4,  6,  5,  5,  5,  5],
       [ 8,  8,  9, 10, 10, 10,  6,  7,  6, 10, 10, 10,  3,  7,  4,  4,  4],
       [ 9,  8, 10,  5,  7,  7, 10, 10,  9,  6,  5,  6,  5,  6,  3,  3,  3],
       [10,  9,  9,  7,  6,  5, 10, 10,  9,  8,  7,  8,  3, 10,  8,  8,  8],
       [10, 10,  8, 10, 10, 10,  2,  5, 10, 10, 10,  9,  7,  9,  3,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  4,  5,  3,  2,  2,  9,  8,  4,  2,  2,  3,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5],
       [ 4,  4,  4,  7,  5,  6,  4,  4,  4,  5,  6,  7, 10,  2,  8,  8,  8],
       [ 7,  8,  6,  6,  8,  8,  7,  9,  8,  7,  8,  7,  9,  8,  6,  6,  6],
       [ 8,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,  9,  5,  7,  7,  7,  5,  7,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  1,  1,  1,  9,  7,  7,  1,  1,  1,  9,  3,  4,  4,  4],
       [ 2,  5,  6,  1,  1,  2,  7,  5,  6,  1,  2,  2,  8,  4,  1,  1,  1],
       [10, 10,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  3, 10,  7,  7,  7],
       [ 6,  3,  4,  9,  9,  9,  8,  7,  5,  9,  9, 10,  1,  2, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 9, 10, 10,  9,  9,  9,  1,  8, 10,  9,  9,  9,  8,  4,  9,  9,   9]])

columns = ["feature1", "feature2", "feature3", "feature4", "feature5", "feature6", "feature7", "feature8", "feature9", "feature10", "feature11", "feature12", "feature13", "feature14", "feature15", "feature16", "feature17"]

indexes = ['AAPL', 'AMGN', 'AXP', 'BA', 'CAT', 'CRM', 'CSCO', 'CVX', 'DIS', 'GS',
       'HD', 'HON', 'IBM', 'INTC', 'JNJ', 'JPM', 'KO', 'MCD', 'MMM', 'MRK',
       'MSFT', 'NKE', 'PG', 'TRV', 'UNH', 'V', 'VZ', 'WBA', 'WMT']

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=columns, index=indexes)
```

Using this code:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10), dpi=600)
a = sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, cmap="RdBu_r", square=True, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

I want to adjust each cell's size based on its value! I mean, the square cells with the value of 1 should be smaller than those with higher values!
Example:
[image]

Note that this example is not strictly related to the values of the previous heatmap plot! I just provided an example to show what I mean by adjusting each square cell size based on its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This post elaborates on @mwaskom's excellent solution, adapted to the given dataframe.)

For most seaborn functions, it helps to have the dataframe in ["long form"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data).

Here is an example of how your dataframe could be transformed to long form to get to the format used by e.g. `sns.relplot` or `sns.scatterplot`. Probably, it will be easier to start from the original dataframe used to create the pivot table.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.array([[2, 2, 2, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6], [8, 7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 9, 6, 7, 4, 3, 2, 8, 9, 3, 3, 3], [1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 10, 10, 10], [3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 9, 9, 9], [7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 6, 5, 4, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9], [6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 4, 4, 8, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 4], [3, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9, 3, 1, 8, 9, 9, 9, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8], [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 7, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 10, 8, 7, 7, 7], [5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 5, 2, 7, 7, 7], [7, 9, 10, 3, 4, 4, 8, 9, 9, 3, 4, 6, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2], [5, 6, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 9, 10, 2, 2, 2], [4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 7, 10, 10, 10], [2, 1, 1, 8, 8, 8, 1, 4, 2, 8, 8, 8, 4, 1, 5, 5, 5], [9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 2], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 1, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5], [8, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 6, 7, 6, 10, 10, 10, 3, 7, 4, 4, 4], [9, 8, 10, 5, 7, 7, 10, 10, 9, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 3, 3, 3], [10, 9, 9, 7, 6, 5, 10, 10, 9, 8, 7, 8, 3, 10, 8, 8, 8], [10, 10, 8, 10, 10, 10, 2, 5, 10, 10, 10, 9, 7, 9, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 2, 9, 8, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5], [4, 4, 4, 7, 5, 6, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 2, 8, 8, 8], [7, 8, 6, 6, 8, 8, 7, 9, 8, 7, 8, 7, 9, 8, 6, 6, 6], [8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 5, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 9, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 9, 3, 4, 4, 4], [2, 5, 6, 1, 1, 2, 7, 5, 6, 1, 2, 2, 8, 4, 1, 1, 1], [10, 10, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 3, 10, 7, 7, 7], [6, 3, 4, 9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 5, 9, 9, 10, 1, 2, 10, 10, 10], [9, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 1, 8, 10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 4, 9, 9, 9]])
columns = [f"feature{i}" for i in range(1, 18)]
indexes = ['AAPL', 'AMGN', 'AXP', 'BA', 'CAT', 'CRM', 'CSCO', 'CVX', 'DIS', 'GS', 'HD', 'HON', 'IBM', 'INTC', 'JNJ', 'JPM', 'KO', 'MCD', 'MMM', 'MRK', 'MSFT', 'NKE', 'PG', 'TRV', 'UNH', 'V', 'VZ', 'WBA', 'WMT']
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=columns, index=indexes)
df.index.name = 'Ticker'

df_long = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='Ticker', var_name='Feature', value_name='Value')
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
g = sns.relplot(data=df_long, x="Feature", y="Ticker", size="Value", hue="Value",
                marker="s", sizes=(20, 200), palette="blend:limegreen,orange", height=8, aspect=1.1)
g.ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
g.ax.set_facecolor('aliceblue')
g.ax.grid(color='red', lw=1)

g.fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.15)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.relplot using long form dataframe]

Comment: Can the distance between horizontal lines be modified to achieve a perfect squared grid? They're like rectangles now! I mean, the distance between horizontal lines should equal that between vertical lines!

Comment: You might want to experiment with `g.ax.set_aspect('equal')`

Comment: Thanks! And what if I want to specify the distance by myself? I tried `from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator; g.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(10));
g.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(10))` but it throws `'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'yaxis'` error.

Comment: You can't change the distance via the `locator`; it is meant for numeric ticks, not for strings. Anyway, the syntax would be `g.ax.set_...`.  Note that `g` is a `FacetGrid`.  To change the distances, you need to work with the `height=` parameter of `sns.relplot`.

Answer (score 3):

This is something you can accomplish with `scatterplot` or `relplot`:

```
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
g = sns.relplot(
    data=flights,
    x="year", y="month", size="passengers", hue="passengers",
    marker="s", sizes=(40, 400), palette="blend:b,r",
)
```

[image]

Comment: I think this isn't. Because if the y-axis contains duplicate values, then some squares overlap exactly! I don't want to miss any squares! This is only achievable using something like a heat map plot! Example: (0, 1), (0, 1) are two data points which take exactly the same place in the plot you proposed.

Comment: Add a suffix or something to distinguish them — I don't see how someone would be able to interpret the heatmap with identical tick labels even if it draws them separately.

Comment: It isn't identical. In my example (first image), I have a matrix that contains the score of each stock in terms of a set of unique features. For example, the score of apple stock (first row) in terms of the first feature (first column) is 2. Also, the score of Intel stock ( 14'th row) in terms of the first feature (first column) is 2. These shouldn't overlap in the plot! Exactly in the way illustrated in the first image! Finally, the first image is achieved and is okay, The only issue and focus of this question is to adjust the size of each cell according to the scores.

Comment: I agree with the comment from @johanc that it's not possible to understand what your problem with this solution is given that you don't provide sample data. This solution will draw a square for each unique combination of the x and y values. In any case, this is the best you're going to get, because it's not possible to modulate the size of each cell using the heatmap function..

Comment: Question updated and the data provided. I appreciate any help.